# why Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop
How can I fix this to prevent infinite rendering?

Do not put ()=> in multiple places.

```
export default function Test1() {
  const [ref, inView] = useInView({ threshold: 0, triggerOnce: true });
  const [num, setNum] = useState(10);
  console.log(ref);

  if (inView) {
    setNum(num + 10);
    // console.log(num + 10);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Diiv1>123</Diiv1>
      <Diiv2 ref={ref}>Element {inView.toString()}</Diiv2>
      <Diiv3>789</Diiv3>
    </div>
  );
}
const Diiv1 = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: blue;
`;

const Diiv2 = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: red;
`;

const Diiv3 = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: blue;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Move this to a useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if (inView) {
    setNum(num + 10);
    // console.log(num + 10);
  }
},[num,ref])
```

Update:
actually, you should do this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.threshold) {
      setNum(num + 10);
      // console.log(num + 10);
    }
  }, [ref,numb]);
```

[image]

Comment: it's not work.. .. .. . .. . . . .

Comment: Can you give me the useInView hook?